# How do I use ext3cow?

Tags: filesystem

A while ago I looked at the ext3cow file system. I am interested in getting it running under lucid. I was wondering whether anyone had successfully set it up on their system and could offer any tips? I have had a quick google around but not found any mentions of getting it working under Ubuntu.

http://www.ext3cow.com/

Comment: What's your question? The documentation on the website says it is transparent to the kernel.

Comment: Could you tell me how to install the ext3cow?I was annoying for a long time this matter.Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I too looked at ext3cow a while ago and spent some time in setting things up and testing.

What I found and what I suspect you will find, is that what you really require is distributed VCS such as [bzr](http://bazaar.canonical.com/en/).

Having the file system history is very useful and ext3cow takes care of this for you automatically without the hassle of having to commit. But in reality having the *option* to commit, add log details, revert easily and [graphically view the history](http://wiki.bazaar.canonical.com/Olive) makes the committing a small overhead to manage.

Answer (score 1):

As there website says:

• It is totally modular, requiring no changes to kernel or VFS interfaces

It hasn't been in development for a couple of years. I am doubtful but hopeful give it a try.

Or maybe look at some [alternatives](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem).

Comment: Funnily, the package ttfm (Time Travelling File Manager) is in the repositories that states:
"you need a patched kernel with ext3cow support AND the snapshot utility in order to properly use this application"

Comment: I missed that bit was looking at the Download page where there is a big Kernel patch you need to apply to get it to work. 
http://www.ext3cow.com/Download.html
Looking at the alternatives on that page, some of them look interesting like Btrfs.

Comment: @Marcel I had noticed that as well. First thing I did when I wanted to check it out was an apt-cache search and thats the only thing that pops up in relation.

Comment: @Mark any luck?

Comment: @garbagecollector I am going to give it a go on one of VPS boxes shortly. Will keep ya up-to-date with success or failure.

Comment: @Mark Of course that's what I did as well ;) But what I meant with "funnily" is that the ttfm description mentions a necessary kernel patch whereas the statement on the website sounds as if no changes to the kernel are necessary...

Comment: Yea I get what you mean @Marcel I didn't mean to dismiss your comment. You are completely right does seem to contraindicate itself.

Comment: Not had any luck with the patch with kernel 2.6.32
Its failing to patch might have to try an older kernel.

Answer (score 1):

In the path of alternatives, there are other copy-on-write filesystems, like `btrfs` and `copyfs`.